# How to find the line through $A=(x,y)$ and parallel to the line $b:(x,y)+\lambda(a,b)$

Tags: geometry

I have to find the line through the point $A=(x,y)$ and parallel to the line $b:(x,y)+\lambda(a,b)$. I know the process if I have the cartesian form of the line, I simply use the formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, but what if I have the vectorial form?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your notations:

$$b:(a,b)+\lambda(x,y)$$

So the slope is $\lambda$

$$A=(x_A,y_A)$$

The parallel line has the same slope:

$$a:A+\lambda(x,y)$$
or
$$a:(x_A,y_A)+\lambda(x,y)$$

Comment: Sorry, $A=(x_a,x_a)$ is the given point?

Comment: If you use $x$ and $y$ for showing a fixed point, then you cannot use it to show variable $x$ and $y$ of the line.

Comment: @GrouchoMarx in your notation, b is already passing $(x,y)$ !

Comment: But, what is $A=(x_a,x_a)$?

Comment: @GrouchoMarx apologize for my mistake